# Why the preloader doesn't dissapear?

Tags: jquery, css, preloader

I am loading a page inside a #section and the page is around 450kb, so I'm trying to install a preloader.

The problem is that the preloader never disappears and I'm not sure if I'm using the right the code. I've got the CSS code in another file, and inside the heavy HTML which is loaded in the section of my index I am placing the script until the head ends, and the `#preloader` div is at the beginning of the `body`.

The questions are, in first place are the codes where they should be? And why does it not work?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).load(function () {
          $('#preloader').delay(2500).fadeOut('slow');
          $('body').delay(2500).css({
              'overflow': 'visible'
          });
      })
</script>
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#preloader {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 45%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-45%);
}
.spinner div {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: move 4s infinite cubic-bezier(.2,.64,.81,.23);
}
.spinner div:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 150ms;
}
.spinner div:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 300ms;
}
.spinner div:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 450ms;
}
@keyframes move {
  0% {left: 0%;}
  75% {left:100%;}
  100% {left:100%;}
}
```

```html
<div id="preloader">
  <div class="spinner">
    <div style="background-color:#f48fb1"></div>
    <div style="background-color:#e91e63"></div>
    <div style="background-color:#f8bbd0"></div>
    <div style="background-color:#f06292"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try using $(document).ready instead?

Comment: Did you check if $(window).load gets called at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by hiddin the overflow and showing the loader in the prev page when I click the link, and when the new page loads the preloader automatically dissapears!

Thanks to all for your knowledge that makes me continue learning.

Answer (score 1):

try `$(document).ready()` instead of `$(window).load()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#preloader').delay(2500).fadeOut('slow');
  $('body').delay(2500).css({
    'overflow': 'visible'
  });
})
```

Comment: Yes, this works. The .load() method is deprecated and was removed in version 3.0 according to the docs.

Comment: It works better I think with $(document).ready() because previously when I resized the window with the $(document).load() I had no scrolls, now I ve got the scrolls but the preloader is still there, and I noticed something else, the preloader starts once the page is already loaded so when it doesn't need a preloader anymore, Should I call the preloader in the previous page and close it in the new one?! I'm lost... Thanks.

Comment: Now I noticed that It works and dissapears when I open the page that I load alone, the problem that the preloaader does not dissapear is when I load the page under the section of the index.html, maybe I should try  something else to refer to the preloader, somethig like $('#section #preloader'), but obviously didn't work.